# Byte[] to List<string> makes Visual Studio crash

Tags: string, zip, compression

For some reason my code makes Visual Studio crash completely and close itself.

I have some idea it's because of the string length, as I'm working with a .zip file that is 88 MB before it is unzipped.

Below is my code.

As you can see, I have tried to split up the byte[] in smaller parts, but that didn't help => I think it's the string length that makes it fail.

```
byte[] decompressed = Decompress(File.ReadAllBytes(localFilename));

List<string> list = null;
if (decompressed.Length > 50000000)
{
    byte[] first = decompressed.Take(50000000).ToArray();
    byte[] second = decompressed.Skip(50000000).ToArray();

    string decompressedString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(first);
    decompressedString += System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(second);

    string[] decompressedStringArray = decompressedString.Split('\n');
    list = new List<string>(decompressedStringArray);
}
else
{
    string decompressedString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(decompressed);

    string[] decompressedStringArray = decompressedString.Split('\n');
    list = new List<string>(decompressedStringArray);
}
```

Any ideas for how I can improve my code so it doesn't make Visual Studio crash? (i.e. how to go from byte[] to List in a better way?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you try this with a small zip and it worked ok ?

Comment: Yes, no problems at all with smaller zips.

Comment: What's the size of the data, and do you really need to hold all of it in an array in memory ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix:

```
List<string> list = null;
if (decompressed.Length > 50000000)
{
    byte[] first = decompressed.Take(50000000).ToArray();
    string decompressedString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(first);
    string[] decompressedStringArray = decompressedString.Split('\n');
    list = new List<string>(decompressedStringArray);

    byte[] second = decompressed.Skip(50000000).ToArray();
    decompressedString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(second);
    decompressedStringArray = decompressedString.Split('\n');
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>(decompressedStringArray);

    list.AddRange(list2);
}
else
{
    string decompressedString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(decompressed);

    string[] decompressedStringArray = decompressedString.Split('\n');
    list = new List<string>(decompressedStringArray);
}
```